# Return Stored Procedures, tables and columns in reference to a particular database

Tags: sql-server, database, stored-procedures, sql-view

I am looking to write a query that will return all of the stored procedures and views that reference a specific database that I am looking to rebuild.  I also need the query to return the columns and table names that the returned stored procedures / views contain in reference to the database being rebuilt.

I have a query right now that will return the stored procs and views, but have been unsuccessful in returning the column and table names that reference the database.

```
SELECT Distinct so.Name, so.type--, sc.text
FROM sysobjects so(NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN syscomments sc (NOLOCK) on so.Id = sc.ID

WHERE so.Type in( 'p' , 'v')
AND sc.Text LIKE '%membership_dw.%'
ORDER BY so.Name
```

Membership_DW is the name of the database where the stored procedures and views are currently stored, and it is also the database that is being recreated.

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding what you are trying to do. But you should be careful throwing that NOLOCK hint all over the place. It is far more sinister than most people realize. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: Perhaps you need to look at sys.sysdepends? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-compatibility-views/sys-sysdepends-transact-sql

Comment: I need the sp/views that reference this database/tables/columns because they are going to have to be rewritten to point to the new database instead.  There are a lot of stored procedures housed in Membership_DW that don't reference the Membership_DW database at all. I will play around with the sysdepends and see what I can get out of it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick and dirty query to do it

```
;WITH cte as(
select * 
from sys.sysdepends t1
inner join sys.objects t2 on t1.depid = t2.object_id
where t2.type = 'U' and is_ms_shipped = 0)
SELECT t5.name as SP_NAME, t6.name as TBL_NAME, t9.name COLNAME from         sys.objects t5 
INNER JOIN cte t6 on t6.id = t5.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.columns t9 on t6.object_id = t9.object_id
where t5.is_ms_shipped = 0 and t6.name not like 'sys%'
order by sp_name, TBL_NAME
```